# Are there any rabbinical opinions that understand Avodah Zara to be more as it translates(foreign service), rather than just "idol worship"

Tags: avodah-zarah

Are there any rabbinical opinions that understand Avodah Zara to be more as it translates(foreign service), rather than just "idol worship".

i.e. Does Avodah Zara really just refer to idolatry, or does it actually refer to foreign service regardless of whether that foreign service is idolatrous?

I understand that rabbis seem to view Avoda Zara as meaning idolatry. And for example some consider islam to be idol worship https://www.jerusalem-herald.com/single-post/2017/12/13/Is-Islam-Idolatry  and some consider it to not be, particularly post RAMBAM.

But let's suppose we accept that islam is not idol worship, as the RAMBAM said.

Isn't it still foreign service.

The service is foreign. e.g. pilgrimage to saudi arabia to visit the black stone. (even if we accept that it's not idolatry)

Similarly with Sikhism.

These are services to God that are extremely foreign.. I'm wondering if any rabbinical opinions view avodah zara that way?

Comment: Isn't "foreign service" and “idol worship” the same thing?

Comment: The expression “foreign service” never appears in the Chumash; it’s consistently “do not worship other gods” or “do not worship the sun and moon” or the like.

Comment: Some Jews practice "foreign service." For example, the Christian notion of “original sin,” is not Jewish but of Christian theology. Yet many Jews belive in the doctrine of “original sin." I once heard a rabbi say he believed in “original sin.” The "Evil eye" is also "foreign service," as well as many concepts in Jewish mysticism. Many practices that Jew follow today are not Jewish but pagan. If you mean that "foreign practices that have entered Judaism tragically to be pagan than it is "foreign service" but not necessary idolatry.

Comment: So you're asking whether working in your country's embassy overseas would be considered _avoda zara_, just (unlike idolatry) __a permitted form of__ _avoda zara_? Well, every word means whatever the participants in the conversation mean it to mean....

Comment: I think we have to start with the notion that the phrase Avodah Zarah is a later coinage to refer to behaviors that were forbidden (not a category of behavior that is created VIA the phrase). Idolatry was forbidden in the Torah. A later set of words is used to refer to what was forbidden in the Torah. It capitalized on the notion of "avodah" as worship (avodah she'ba'lev, or avodah as the sacrificial system) and "zarah" as strange or foreign. So this is religious behavior that is foreign to us.

Comment: Tehillim 81 el zar seems to be relevant לֹא יִהְיֶה בְךָ אֵל זָר וְלֹא תִשְׁתַּחֲוֶה לְאֵל נֵכָר

Comment: @DonielF Shemot 30:9 (and Vayikra 10:1 etc.)

Comment: A lot of those practices would seem to fall under the category of chukkos hagoyim (following in the ways of the non-Jews). The original source for that is Vayikra 18:3 (ובחוקותיהם לא תלכו), and some details are in Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 178 (note that this is distinct from the laws about idolatry and relations with idol-worshipers proper, which are in sections 139-158).

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps I wasn’t clear; I intended that it wasn’t used in the context of idolatry.

Comment: @DonielF Ok, but as the OP thought it does appear to describe non traditional ways of serving God. What's the difference between Nadav and Avihu and Islam?

Comment: @DonielF  Looking at DoubleAA's chumash references, they don't use the phrase Avodah Zara. Though they do refer to Zara/strange in reference to offerings, strange incense, and strange fire.   Ex 30:9  "Ketoret Zara" (strange incense).   Lev 10:1  "Aish Zara" (strange fire).

Comment: @msh210 No not a foreign office job.  But sering God in a foreign way, for example,living as a Sikh(non-idolatrous religion). Is it called Avodah Zara in rabbinical opinions? And i'm asking about how the term is used in a halachic sense. or in rabbinical writing, aside from references to idolatry.

Comment: @barlop: Offering incense and whole-burnt sacrifices are forms of worship; unless, of course, you think that the priests in question were pyromaniacs (!), burning things just for fun.

Comment: @Lucian of course they are forms of worship, but generalising for all forms of worship is another matter. Like a text could say "don't eat apples", "don't eat oranges".  You could try to extrapolate "don't eat fruit", but the text didn't say "don't eat bananas". And it's worth noting what phrase/phrases is/are used and what phrase isn't used.

Comment: @barlop: You said that the exact expression does not occur; I tried to explain why. That's all. Even if not all strange forms of worship would be forbidden (which is what you seem to be arguing, if I am understanding you correctly ?), even then, one would still, in practice, prefer simple, catch-all phrases (such as this) over longer ones (such as strange gods, fire, and incense), with a greater number of wagons, so to say.

Comment: @Lucian so we have the Chumash referring to particular forms of service to God, that are foreign.. Have the rabbis ever used the term avodah zara in that sense though? (i'm aware rabbis have referred to idol worship as avodah zara., but have they ever referred to foreign forms of worshipping God - not idol worship, but foreign practises?).